# Small error in the translation of transactional email

Tags: email, localisation

In Magento 1.9.1 I've installed the German language pack. Everything looks fine except of a very small problem in the email subject for the shipping mail:

English:
Shipment # 100000001 for Order # 100000004

German:
Versand Nr. 200000002 für Bestellung Nr. {{var order.increment_id}

In the official Magento documentation you can read: "Only the en_US templates were updated to the new responsive email structure. To use the responsive emails for other locales, copy the en_US/template/email/ directory into the respective app/locale/[LOCALE CODE] directory and update the text strings to that locale."
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/RWD_responsive_emails.html#localizing

I had a look in this folder but there were no German translation in it. Is there another location where I should look for it?
The problem is maybe only a missing }

I don't want to build up everything from the scratch. The other emails and translations are fine.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you will need to copy all files to a folder called `de_DE` under `locale` from 'locale/en_US`.

If you cannot find `de_DE` folder in `locale` then just create one.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't want to build up the template for German email from the scratch. The German emails are perfect except for the subject in the shipping mail. I cannot see the order no. there, just "{{var order.increment_id}". I think it should be easy possible to change. If I would know about the right file location.